# B-trees before and after insertion and deletion

Tags: tree, b-tree

I wanted to ask, if I have a B-tree and I first **insert** a number and then **delete** it, is the tree going to **stay the same** as the tree before the insertion and deletion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After the insert/delete sequence the B-tree may look different physically.

For example, the insertion of the key might cause one or more nodes to split and these will most likely *stay split* when you remove the key afterwards. Also, either operation might cause rebalancings via borrowing/lending of keys, without any node splits or node merges. What exactly happens depends on the details of the particular rebalancing strategy that was chosen for your particular B-tree implementation.

Note: if the insertion causes a restructuring that is subsequently reversed by the deletion then this would have to be regarded as a *failure* of the rebalancing strategy, because avoiding such oscillation is one of the objectives of a restructuring policy.

The B-tree definition does not prescribe any specific rebalancing strategy - that's free for the implementer to choose, as long as the invariants of the B-tree are respected. The important thing is that the *logical view* will be the same before and after, meaning that queries return exactly the same results.